# WPF-MediaKit cant render some H264 video on my project but it can elsewhere

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, media, wpf-mediakit

I'm trying to use the MediaUriElement from WPF-MediaKit, it works fine for every format I've tested except with the H264 format.

[image: Left: My application, Right: WPF Mediakit Sample application, Video codec: Codec H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)(avc1), FrameRate: 29.969000, Res:320x240]

Picture: Left: My application, Right: WPF Mediakit Sample application

Whats strange is that WPF mediakit in my application can play file that is:

```
Codec H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)(avc1), FrameRate: 24.000384, Res: 1920x872
```

But it cant play: (i'm using this video as an example, it cant play other similar videos)

```
Codec H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)(avc1), FrameRate: 29.969000, Res: 320x240
```

I spent a fair while looking through the source code for the WPFMediakit sample application, but i couldn't figure out what they did diffrently.

I have K light codec installed and Windows media player can play the videos.

If you need other information I'll be happy to provide them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved, I dont know why but WPFMediaKit has trouble running under the VS debug environment. It works fine when the release build is run.